# Striking electronics facts, stories or puzzles

Tags: education

Say you are at a dinner table with like-minded, curious people, and you want to share your enthusiasm for electronics.

How would you entertain your audience? Would it be a Steve Jobs story, a summary of a recent breakthrough, some sort of puzzle, etc.?

<sub>P.S. I'm hoping the Electronics StackExchange community will enjoy this more lighthearted topic and not close the question off. :)</sub>

Comment: What's the difference between electrical engineer and mechanical engineer?  Electrical engineers work with currents under 100mA.  (This joke might lead a conversation about difference between electrical engineer and electronics engineer.)

Comment: @NickAlexeev - I don't get the joke, but most electrical engineers work with currents under 100 MA.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Haha! That's great, I'm going to use that one on my ECE friends now. :-P

Comment: You can make things like this :-) (won't enthuse everyone). - http://goo.gl/ixMMv . For those it does enthuse, the 'rewards' are better than significant amounts of $.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon  I think that the point of the joke is that at high currents (and high voltages) mechanical engineering problems become more prominent.  Conductor sizes, clearances, heat dissipation.  At least that's what the point was under the circumstances when I was told this joke by power electronics guys.

Comment: Make a chat room and post on meta about making a chatroom to discuss this, that is a really good for something like this discussion, the main site is not a place for something like this. Nice pictures @RussellMcMahon.

Comment: @Kortuk: Really? Come on...

Comment: @Kortuk - I didn't take any of those photos alas, just made the lights. Most of the ... checks ... 125,000 photos on that site are mine. A very variable bag. fwiw (and largely apropos of nothing) a somewhat whimiscal mix of photos I like for their memories are at http://goo.gl/Li5B5 (roll down)